# Failed to import “Contact form 1”: Invalid post type wpcf7_contact_form Failed to import Media “db_site.sql_.txt”

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new to web development specially with wordpress. I created a website using wordpress as cms framework. I imported a database to my wordpress dashboard, all went well but the problem was some of the content was never imported successfully and the message is this,

"...Failed to import Media “db_site.sql_.txt” and Failed to import “Contact form 1”: Invalid post type wpcf7_contact_form.."

what could be the problem with this? I appreciate any help from you. Thanks!..=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the required WordPress plugin:

- install and activate plugin **Contact Form 7**
- import the theme again...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new SO user, and therefore I can't comment on the question itself, but I think I can help.  Forgive me if I post an answer that is actually a comment, but I think that's my best option.  I'll edit this question to become an answer once things have been clarified.

Your phrase, "I imported a database to my wordpress dashboard" doesn't exactly make sense.  Where was the data initially?  What sort of data was in it?  What tool are you using to do the import?