# Importing an xml file in wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins, import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to import “Contact form 1”: Invalid post type wpcf7_contact_form Failed to import Media “db_site.sql_.txt”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589905/failed-to-import-contact-form-1-invalid-post-type-wpcf7-contact-form-failed-t)

I imported an .xml file in wordpress, it work well but some of the contents were not imported instead it displayed a certain error message,..

"...Failed to import Media “db_site.sql_.txt”
Failed to import “Contact form 1”: Invalid post type wpcf7_contact_form.."

what could be the problem with this? I appreciate any help from you. Thanks!..=)

Answer (score 1):

Hi There is some thing left while exporting whole database, contact from 7 data is left while exporting...

Comment: Hi!..i have imported it to one of my pc then at first it worked..the contact form 7 had been imported successfully but when i tried importing it to another pc the contact form 7 was not imported successfully anymore..

Comment: Then try execute whole database in a query, first drop all table and then execute query...